# Cannot solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/appcheck/interop/InternalAppCheckTokenProvider

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was building an app one year ago. The app was working perfectly at that time. After a year, I want to run the app again but now when I run the app this error is showed everytime.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/appcheck/interop/InternalAppCheckTokenProvider;                                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseRegistrar.getComponents(DatabaseRegistrar.java:38)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.tracing.ComponentMonitor.processRegistrar(ComponentMonitor.java:28)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:117)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init>(ComponentRuntime.java:99)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init>(ComponentRuntime.java:46)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build(ComponentRuntime.java:387)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:439)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:296)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:264)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:249)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:66)
                                                                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2429)
                                                                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2399)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:58)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:8190)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7726)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7546)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:301)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.appcheck.interop.InternalAppCheckTokenProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~KSAGapddSqoZ-CllJmTAyw==/com.application.testApp-xwYLI9_QcCtUIHFtUwAMCM==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~KSAGapddSqoZ-CllJmTAyw==/com.application.testApp-xwYLI9_QcCtUIHFtUwAMCM==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~KSAGapddSqoZ-CllJmTAyw==/com.application.testApp-xwYLI9_QcCtUIHFtUwAWCw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Here is my build.gradle(:app) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 33
buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.application.testapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.0.2'

// Add the SDK for Firebase Cloud Messaging
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck:17.0.1'

implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

}
```

Here is my build.gradle(:testapp) file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    //For Glide
    mavenCentral()
    
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    //Zoom in/out
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Android Gradle Plugin Version 3.5.2 and Gradle Version is 5.4.1

Please help me to solve the problem. I search the solution on Internet but unfortunately not able to solve the problem. Thank you.